# Replication between two storage accounts in different regions, must be read/writeable and zone redundant

Tags: azure-storage

We are setting up an active/active configuration using either front door or traffic manager as our front end. Our services are located in both Central and East US 2 paired regions. There is an AKS cluster in each region. The AKS clusters will write data to a storage account located in their region. However, the files in the storage accounts must be the same in each region. The storage accounts must be zone redundant and read/writeable in each region at all times, thus none of the Microsoft replication strategies work. This replication must be automatic, we can't have any manual process to do the copy. I looked at Data Factory but it seems to be regional, so I don't think that would work, but it's a possibility....maybe. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

Replication between two storage accounts can be implemented using the Logic App.

In the logic app, we can create two workflows. One for replicating data from storage account 1 to storage account 2. Other for replicating data from storage account 2 to storage account 1.

I have tried to replicate blob data between storage accounts in different regions.

The workflow is :

When a blob is added or modified in the storage account 1, the blob will be copied to the storage account 2

**Trigger** : When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2) (Use connection setting of storage account1)

[image]

**Action** : Copy blob (V2) ) (Use connection setting of storage account2)

[image]

Similar way, we can create another workflow for replication of data from Storage Account 2 to Storage Account 1.

Now, the data will be replicated between the two storage accounts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your info, the part of that process which isn't working for me is that when I run the trigger in the designer, the history shows that it was "skipped."  I'm running it manually from within the designer after having uploaded files to the source storage account; nothing shows up in the destination and the run history for the app shows that it's never run, each manually run shows up as "skipped" in the trigger history.

Answer (score 0):

Object replication is another option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/object-replication-overview

I have the same requirement of active/active and I'm considering this as the first option I'll try.